# how to validate the date after the current date in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, date, validation

I need to make the the date validation to be after the current date. I tried this:

```
Router.post('/home', [
    check('due_date')
        .isDate()
        .isAfter(new Date.now())
        .withMessage("The date should be in the future, after the current time."),
],(req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).send({errors: errors.array()});

    TPost.postT(req.body).then(message => {
        return res.json(message);
    }).catch((error) => {
        return res.json(404, error);
    });
});
```

But it does not work, as I got the error: `TypeError: Date.now is not a constructor`.

Comment: "Date.now is not a constructor" - so `new Date.now()` doesn't make sense. Just do `Date.now()`, it's a static method that returns a number: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: Also assuming you're using https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js it seems like `isAfter` defaults to now anyway.

Comment: Than you very much @jonrsharpe you saved me! Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.isAfter(new Date())
```

on line 4

You can use "moment" to validate, manipulate and compare dates.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe mentioned, it works even without new Date() at all inside. So now it works.Thank you very much!

Comment: @Roxana I suspect if you use `new Date()` like this it will only check that inputs are after the server start time, because you only call `new Date()` once. So in a day or two (unless the server happens to restart more often) you'll be able to enter dates in the past.